# MySQL Workbench doesn't shown export option on macOS sierra

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Workbench (v 6.3.9) on my mac macOS Sierra 10.12.4.
There are several problems with displays.
I do not have access to export options in "Forward Engineer SQL Script", there is no text in the catalog in the left panel (and more...).

[image]

[image]

What can I do to workaround these problems?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, MYSQL Workbench (v 6.3.9) is buggy, though it is still possible to do Forward Engineer through Database->Synchronize Model. An alternative to viewing the text in the catalog is clicking the layers option on the right to display your tables.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

Indeed, I can make the tables appear by choosing "layer". Thank you.

On the other hand, for exporting tables (Forward Engineer through Database-> Synchronize Model) your solution does not solve my problem because I have to export the tables with the option "INSERT". Indeed, I have data in my model and I have to export them.
Forward Engineer through Database-> Synchronize Model does not allow it!

cordially

Answer (score 0):

Every software has bugs, it's just sometimes less obvious (here however very). No doubt, both are serious problems. The first one is already known and we will fix it for the next release. The second problem however is surprising. I just tried the version available from the MySQL website and the catalog tree shows fine for me. Would be good if you could [create a bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com) for that, so we can fix that too.